# AWS - Grant Cognito permissions to use SES using Python CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, aws-cdk, amazon-ses

from [enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-email.html#user-pool-email-developer) under "Step 3: Grant email permissions to Amazon Cognito"(To grant permissions to use your Amazon SES configuration): "Before Amazon Cognito can create this role, the IAM permissions that you use to set up your user pool must include the iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole action"

- How do I know what the IAM permissions that I use to set up my user pool are?
- How do I make them include the iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole action?
  I use python cdk to create my user pool.

Comment: This just means that the role doing the deployment has to have this permission. This will be the CloudFormation execution role in case of CDK, it's created as part of bootstrapping and has `AdministratorAccess` by default. You don't have to add anything.